# Liquid template: Get first 5 posts that match criterion

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to display the 5 most recent posts which have a thumbnail on the main page of my jekyll-blog. How to achieve this?

I set the thumnail as an attribut in the header of the post:

```
---
layout: post
title: Lorem Ipsum
thumb: images/thumb.jpg
---
```

I tried

```
{% for post in site.posts | sort:"date" | reverse | limit: 5 %}
    {% if post.thumb %}
        <img src= ... />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but of course, if one of the five happens not to have a picture, only four will be displayed. Is there a smooth way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
{% assign maxPost = 5 %}
{% assign counter = 0 %}
{% for post in site.posts | sort:"date" | reverse %}
    {% if post.thumb %}
        <img src= ... />
        {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
        {% if counter == maxPost %}
            {% break %} {% comment %}exit the for loop{% endcomment %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! (although the "limit" has to be removed now). 
I suppose there is no really elegant solution like another "filter", e.g. {% for post in site.posts | has_property:"thumb" ... %}?

Comment: Then maybe you can approve the answer. You can filter an array on a variable : `{% assign posts = site.posts where myVar = "toto" %}` then loop over `posts`.